# Get object/item on button click (dynamically created button) - stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf, button, stackpanel

I am looping my customers, and for each  customer I need to create one button in case
I would like to delete that specific customer.

So here is my code:

```
foreach (var item in customersList)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Content = "Customer": + " " + item.Value;
    btn.Height = 40;
    btn.Click += btn_Click;

    TextBox cust = new TextBox();
    cust.Height = 40;
    cust.Text = item.Value;

    stackCustomers.Children.Add(cust);
    stackCustomers.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

How could I attach event Click on my button so when I click on It I get customer?

```
void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
    //I tried this but it is not working, unfortunatelly...
    Customer cust = (Customer)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way: attach customer to the `Button.Tag` property

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Tag = item; // .Value maybe?

// ...

void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    Customer cust = (Customer)button.Tag;
}
```

What might be better: Create a visual representation of each customer item, where the button is contained. Use `Button.Command` and `Button.CommandParameter={Binding PathToCustomer}` instead of `Button.Click`.

Comment: it is working! and about better solution, could you explain me that a bit? Thans a lot!

Comment: @Roxy'Pro you should provide some more of what you have in terms of XAML and customersList, then I can try to explain possible changes.

Comment: ok I will provide it later, now I am wondering how can I put textbox + button in stackpanel but to keep it next to each other, If I set Orientation="Horizontal" than it looks ugly, should I open new question for this?  Thanks again dude

Comment: @Roxy'Pro first, think of your desired layout (placement, size, ...) then ask yourself if a `StackPanel` is the right choice (you could use `Grid`, `DockPanel`, ...). If you know your desired layout, you will find ways to show it. Make sure that you research your stuff before asking a question about it - most things will already have an answer.